# How to check if the mouse is over a gameObject in phaser 3?

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a game object (specifically, a rectangle). I want to display text that follows the mouse only when hovering over the rectangle.

I tried using a `rectangle.on('pointover', function(pointer) {...})` listener, but that only catches the initial mouse over event. It won't fire continuously to allow the text to follow the mouse.

I assume I need something in my `update()` method like:

```
if (rectangle.onPointerOver()) {
   update text x and y from pointer
}
```

But I don't see any such method on the [GameObject](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.GameObject.html) or [Rectangle](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Rectangle.html).

I also know I could naively find the x and y coordinates and length and width of the rectangle and check that against the pointer, but Phaser 3 must have a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that adding a listener is the right approach, but the event I should be listening for is `.on('pointermove', function(pointer, x, y, event) {})`.

Answer (score 1):

I am definitely late to the party here. Just wanted to fill in some details for anyone who finds this later!

You can definitely use the `pointerover` event when creating your rectangle, just like any other GameObject.
You just need to make sure you call setInteractive() on the game object first.

```js
const rect = this.add.rectangle(200, 200, 148, 148, 0x6666ff);
rect.setInteractive()
rect.on("pointerover", () => {
    rect.setStrokeStyle(4, 0xefc53f);
});
```

Also, for future reference:

I couldn't find the full list of available input events in the docs, but here they are in the git repo.

https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/master/src/input/events/index.js

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this:

```
gameObject.setInteractive().on('pointerdown', function(pointer, localX, localY, event){
    // ...
});
```

I don't know how to change this for hover, but maybe this helps someone.